# How to find/replace a <script> HTML tag recursively in all files with Bash/sed?

Tags: bash, recursion, replace, sed

I have to find and replace a "script" HTML tag recursively in all files inside a directory and I'd like to do it with a bash command and sed. The tag is

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/file.php">< /script>
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

***Edit***
As someone told, I haven't specified what I want the replacement to be. Infact "replacement" it's not the right word, because I simply wanted to remove the HTML tag, replacing it with a space or an empty character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sed you can use `sed "s|pattern|replacement|g"` to replace all the "pattern" with "replacement"

Please give the expected output to help others understand your requirement better

Comment: Thanks! With this alternative syntax I only had to escape the " caracther and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

From the information given in question, it seems that you would like to replace a particular string from many HTML files in a given directory.

One way you can do this using sed as follows:

```
sed -i.rep 's/script/replacestring/g' *.html
```

Note that the `-i` option will change the file and create a backup file with the same name with .rep extension with original contents. If you do not want to do this, you may want to iterate over files and do sed and write the results in temporary files. Once you are done, you can inspect them and rename them. For example:

```
for i in *.html
do
  sed 's/script/replacestring/g' $i > rep$i
done
```

In the end, you will have many rep*.html files corresponding to the replaced files.

You can rename/overwrite them as follows:

```
for i in rep*.html
do
  mv $i `echo $i|sed s/rep//`
done
```

The above sed expression will rename the rep files to their original names and will overwrite them.

Comment: The problem here is that the tag string is full of character that need to be escaped, but I don't know ho to do it correctly. I tried prepending every /, ", <, > and : with a backslash, but I didn't worked: the expression is not matched and the file is not changed. Instead, leaving the string as is let sed return me an error.